# Cerrar ventana y borrar localStorage

Tags: web, angular8

Estoy tratando de eliminar en *token* en mi `localStorage`, estoy usando *Angular 8*, se me ocurrio utilizar `HostListener` para controlar el evento de cierre de pantalla:

```
@HostListener("window:load", ["$event"])
    closewindow($event) {

    if ($event===window.onclose) {
        localStorage.clear();
    } 
}
```

Lamentablemente no logro obtener el evento que iguale la condición `If` y logre borrar el `localStorage`. Debo mantener el *token* mientras está actualizándose la página, solo debe eliminarse cuando se cierre la página.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estás escuchando el evento `'load'` en lugar de `'unload'` o `'beforeunload'`, que sería lo correcto:

```
@HostListener('window:beforeunload', ['$event'])
beforeunloadHandler(event) {
    localStorage.clear();
}
```

Comment: Gracias por la colaboración me fe más útil realiar el cambio